# what is the cable and connector type?

Tags: usb, tablet, cable

Can you please help me identify the cable and connector type ? It's USB on one side.

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a mainboard to USB type A female connector. The molex type connection is intended to engage a set of header pins usually found on computer mainboards, although the connector you show is not what one might consider a standard type for such use. It could be intended to connect to an unidentified circuit board, providing a means to attach just about any USB device. One of my 3D printers has this type of cable, although the USB end also has a chassis bracket allowing it to be mounted to a surface. Its purpose is to provide for USB flash drive access.

Without seeing the mainboard for which it is intended, only the general statements above can be made.

Comment: could you please check, it was for this device : https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Android-Car-Player-Touch-screen-USB_1600120601898.html?spm=a2700.pc_countrysearch.main07.66.db2fecbadYNr4Z

Answer (score 0):

The 6 pin connector does not seem to line up with any Molex or JST connectors. There's some resemblance to a number of JST connectors, but either the pitch, number of rows, the housing, the latch, or something else is different.

Taking a small guess, I would say these might be "custom" connectors that are just common in the automotive audio arena? I'm sure somebody manufactures them under a known part number, but looking around at a few of the major connector manufacturers does not turn much up.

This certainly does not belong to a Molex connector though (as the other answer suggested), looking through their parts list on their website shows no configuration like what's shown in your pictures.

I would leave this as a comment, because it's not a solid answer, but I don't have enough reputation here to do that. I hope this provides some form of light on it though.